# Files don't open in browser

Tags: excel, word, pdf

I have newly installed Farm of Sharepoint 2013 on single server

I would like that any files Excel, Pdf, word, powerpoint... opens in browser. I was searching and already applied in advanced settings of the library function to open files in browser.

But when I click on the document it's first downloading it then open in the application.

Comment: I solved The PDF issue, By goint to general settings of my web application in Central Administration and by changing settings of file handling to permissive. Still searching for Word and MS office.

Answer (score 2):

I found my Happiness on this link; 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4d51dc4-6460-437d-aa8e-0ae4d3aa8cc5#singleHTTPS

I did not installed OFFICE WEB APP SERVER.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful, at Site Collection Features:

```
http://YOURSITE/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site
```

Disable:

- Open Documents in Client Applications by Default feature

Comment: This would do exactly oposit of what I need as I need to open everything in Browser no?

Comment: yes, sorry, the answer is to disable...

Comment: have you checked the behaviour disabling the feature?

Comment: When I enter : http://MYSITE/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site I recieve 404 not found

Comment: I opened it via site settings and this feature is disabled already done.